# `include with function definition in system Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a simple system Verilog code with a `include file which has few function definitions. However when I have multiple files which include this file then I get compile error due to function redefinition. Any suggestions how to work around it?

Code test.sv:

```
`include "constants.sv"

module test();

real myReal1;
real myReal2;

initial myReal1 = 10.1;

assign myReal2 = abs(myReal1);

endmodule
```

Code:test2.sv:

```
`include "constants.sv"

module test2();

real myReal1;
real myReal2;

initial myReal1 = 10.1;

assign myReal2 = 10.2;

endmodule
```

Error:

```
function real abs(input real a);
                |
ncvlog: *E,DUPIDN (./constants.sv,19|16): identifier 'abs' previously declared [12.5(IEEE)].
```

Answer (score 1):

a fast solution:

```
`ifndef CONSTANTS
   `define CONSTANTS
   `include "constants.sv"
`endif
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:
Contents of file constants.sv:

```
`ifndef SVINCLUDES

   //define all macros here
   //define all functions here

   `define SVINCLUDES

`endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use package as possible as you can or use include guard to avoid collision

Comment: which include guide are you referring to?

Comment: something like `\`ifndef xxx \n \`define xxx \n \`endif`

Comment: ifndef works only for text macros. Here I want to use `include statement if function is not already defined. Not sure how I can achieve this using ifndef